# How to compare a string with a struct (which include strings too)?

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a project where I'm encountering an issue with my code. I have the following structure:

```
struct adminst {
    string usernameadmin;
    int passwordadmin;
};
```

In addition, I have a function called adminlogin() that looks like this:

```
void adminlogin() {
    string username, password;
    adminst Username[100];
    cout << "Please enter your username: ";
    cin >> username;
    ifstream admin("adminha.txt");
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        admin >> Username[i].usernameadmin;
        if ((Username[i].compare(username)) < 0) {
            // Code block missing
        }
    }
}
```

I also attempted to use the strcmp function as shown below:

```
strcmp(Username[i], usernameadmin) == 0
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not getting any desired results or answers. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in fixing this code.

Comment: You read the string in to `Username[i].usernameadmin` but you try to compare to `Username[i]`. Surely you need to compare to the same thing you read into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be comparing the string WITHIN the struct.

```
Username[i].usernameadmin == username
```

This would compare `string username` with `string usernameadmin`.

The `==` operator can be used to compare strings in C++, thanks to overloading.

You can still use `.compare` as well.

```
Username[i].usernameadmin.compare(username)
```

Comment: Tnx but didn't work! i got this eror : no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to const *" exsists

Comment: oops. Can you try adding `.c_str()` to the end of each string? Such as `username.c_str()`, if the error is occuring within the above snippet?

Comment: Oh my god!! it worked! Thanks a lot! i've been working on this for 3 hours!

Comment: but i dont have any idea what .c_str() it is! can you explain it to me?

Comment: Doing `.c_str()` compares pointers ... this doesn't work.

Comment: Adding `.c_str()` to both in the case of using `==` will give the incorrect behavior. The `.compare()` case should also fail since a `const char*` has no member functions.

Comment: I was thinking the error happened outside the snippet, and adding `c_str()` solved it outside the snippet? I'm pretty sure `==` or `.compare` should work correctly above.

Comment: You can't compare C strings using `==`, you will be comparing adresses of the pointers instead of the data that they are pointing to.

Comment: C++ strings have their `==` operator overloaded, so I presume it would be okay to compare `string`. doing `c_str()` would pose a problem in COMPARING, but I was hoping it solved an error outside the snippet.

Comment: Yeah... i have no idea what are you talking about! but tnx so much.I just tried it over and over and its working.